# "Linear search failed" error initial guess set to minimum of quadratic function

Tags: python, optimization

I've been having trouble with `scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc`.

I am testing the flags of the optimizer using a simple function:

```
f(x)=(x-2)**2+5
```

The optimizer works as expected except when I use the known minimum as the initial guess.

When I do so, I get a message saying `Linear search failed`. Looking around online, this error seems to be saying that the equation is not well behaved, but I know this is not the case.

Why am I getting this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know scipy, but according to the [scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc.html), the function uses a "truncated Newton algorithm". [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) involves dividing by the derivative at the current *x* value, and that's not going to work out well at a minimum (or maximum, or point of inflexion) since the derivative is zero there.

However, scipy-0.15.1 has a closely-related [scipy.optimize.fmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy-optimize-fmin)

> Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.
>
> This algorithm only uses function values, not derivatives or second
>   derivatives.

Hopefully, that one will perform ok near stationary points.